# How to convert huge XML contents into dataframes using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, dictionary

I have tried the below code to convert the sample XML into a dictionary which I later used to convert to a data frame. The sample.xml has only 2 organisations here but it is throwing an error when I am running the actual file with 300,000+ records it is taking ages to run and finally throws error that it is too big.

```
import xmlschema
import pandas as pd
from pprint import print

xs = xmlschema.XMLSchema('Sample.xsd')
dict_xs=xs.to_dict('Sample.xml')
to_convert_to_df = dict_xs['Organisations']
pprint(to_convert_to_df)
```

Sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HSCOrgRefData:OrgRefData xmlns:HSCOrgRefData="http://refdata.hscic.gov.uk/org/v2-0-0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://refdata.hscic.gov.uk/org/v2-0-0 HSCOrgRefData.xsd">
  <Manifest>
    <Version value="2-0-0" />
    <PublicationType value="Full" />
    <PublicationSource value="HSCIC" />
    <PublicationDate value="2022-07-25" />
    <PublicationSeqNum value="1755" />
    <FileCreationDateTime value="2022-07-25T22:14:25" />
    <RecordCount value="278411" />
    <ContentDescription value="HSCOrgRefData_Full_20220725" />
    <PrimaryRoleScope>
      <PrimaryRole id="RO180" displayName="PRIMARY" />
      <PrimaryRole id="RO179" displayName="CARE" />
    </PrimaryRoleScope>
  </Manifest>
  <CodeSystems>
    <CodeSystem name="OrganisationRecordClass" oid="2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.2.4.23">
      <concept id="RC2" code="2" displayName="HSCSite" />
      <concept id="RC1" code="1" displayName="HSCOrg" />
    </CodeSystem>
    <CodeSystem name="OrganisationRole" oid="2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.2.4.17.507">
      <concept id="RO179" code="179" displayName="PRIMARY" />
      <concept id="RO180" code="180" displayName="CARE" />  
    </CodeSystem>
    <CodeSystem name="OrganisationRelationship" oid="2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.2.4.17.508">
      <concept id="RE6" code="6" displayName="IS OPERATED BY" />
    </CodeSystem>
  </CodeSystems>
  <Organisations>
    <Organisation orgRecordClass="RC2">
    <Name>Courtney</Name>
    <Date>
      <Type value="Legal" />
      <Start value="2006-10-01" />
      <End value="2013-03-31" />
    </Date>
    <Date>
      <Type value="Operational" />
      <Start value="2006-10-01" />
    </Date>
    <OrgId root="2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.2.4.18.48" assigningAuthorityName="HSCIC" extension="a12cde" />
    <Status value="Active" />
    <LastChangeDate value="2021-03-26" />
    <GeoLoc>
      <Location>
        <AddrLn1>HIGHLAND ROAD</AddrLn1>
        <Town>SOUTHSEA</Town>
        <County>HAMPSHIRE</County>
        <PostCode>PO4 9HU</PostCode>
        <Country>ENGLAND</Country>
        <UPRN>1775</UPRN>
      </Location>
    </GeoLoc>
    <Roles>
      <Role id="RO180" uniqueRoleId="5785" primaryRole="true">
        <Date>
          <Type value="Legal" />
          <Start value="2006-10-01" />
          <End value="2013-03-31" />
        </Date>
        <Date>
          <Type value="Operational" />
          <Start value="2006-10-01" />
        </Date>
        <Status value="Active" />
      </Role>
    </Roles>
    <Rels>
      <Rel id="RE6" uniqueRelId="178089">
        <Date>
          <Type value="Legal" />
          <Start value="2006-10-01" />
          <End value="2013-03-31" />
        </Date>
        <Date>
          <Type value="Operational" />
          <Start value="2006-10-01" />
          <End value="2020-09-30" />
        </Date>
        <Status value="Inactive" />
        <Target>
          <OrgId root="2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.2.4.18.48" assigningAuthorityName="HSCIC" extension="5QC" />
          <PrimaryRoleId id="RO179" uniqueRoleId="137676" />
        </Target>
      </Rel>
    </Rels>
    <Succs>
      <Succ uniqueSuccId="171">
        <Date>
          <Type value="Legal" />
          <Start value="2006-10-01" />
        </Date>
        <Type>Predecessor</Type>
        <Target>
          <OrgId root="2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.2.4.18.48" assigningAuthorityName="HSCIC" extension="5FD51" />
          <PrimaryRoleId id="RO180" uniqueRoleId="44844" />
        </Target>
      </Succ>
    </Succs>
  </Organisation>
    <Organisation orgRecordClass="RC2">
    <Name>MERLIN</Name>
    <Date>
      <Type value="Legal" />
      <Start value="2006-10-01" />
      <End value="2013-03-31" />
    </Date>
    <Date>
      <Type value="Operational" />
      <Start value="2006-10-01" />
    </Date>
    <OrgId root="2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.2.4.18.48" assigningAuthorityName="HSCIC" extension="b12cde" />
    <Status value="Active" />
    <LastChangeDate value="2021-03-26" />
    <GeoLoc>
      <Location>
        <AddrLn1>VILLIERS ROAD</AddrLn1>
        <Town>SOUTHSEA</Town>
        <County>HAMPSHIRE</County>
        <PostCode>PO5 2HG</PostCode>
        <Country>ENGLAND</Country>
      </Location>
    </GeoLoc>
    <Roles>
      <Role id="RO180" uniqueRoleId="5786" primaryRole="true">
        <Date>
          <Type value="Legal" />
          <Start value="2006-10-01" />
          <End value="2013-03-31" />
        </Date>
        <Date>
          <Type value="Operational" />
          <Start value="2006-10-01" />
        </Date>
        <Status value="Active" />
      </Role>
    </Roles>
    <Rels>
      <Rel id="RE6" uniqueRelId="177836">
        <Date>
          <Type value="Legal" />
          <Start value="2006-10-01" />
          <End value="2013-03-31" />
        </Date>
        <Date>
          <Type value="Operational" />
          <Start value="2006-10-01" />
          <End value="2020-09-30" />
        </Date>
        <Status value="Inactive" />
        <Target>
          <OrgId root="2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.2.4.18.48" assigningAuthorityName="HSCIC" extension="5QC" />
          <PrimaryRoleId id="RO179" uniqueRoleId="137676" />
        </Target>
      </Rel>
    </Rels>
    <Succs>
      <Succ uniqueSuccId="1064">
        <Date>
          <Type value="Legal" />
          <Start value="2006-10-01" />
        </Date>
        <Type>Predecessor</Type>
        <Target>
          <OrgId root="2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.2.4.18.48" assigningAuthorityName="HSCIC" extension="5FD54" />
          <PrimaryRoleId id="RO180" uniqueRoleId="44845" />
        </Target>
      </Succ>
    </Succs>
  </Organisation>
 </Organisations>
</HSCOrgRefData:OrgRefData>
```

Sample.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://refdata.hscic.gov.uk/org/v2-0-0" id="HSCOrgRefData" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://refdata.hscic.gov.uk/org/v2-0-0" xmlns:HSCOrgRefData="http://refdata.hscic.gov.uk/org/v2-0-0">
<xs:element name="OrgRefData" type="OrgType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>This is the root element of the XML document.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="OrgType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Container for the Manifest, CodeSystems and Payload.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Organisations" type="OrgOrganisationsType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="PrimaryRoleScopeType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>List of Primary Roles for subject records in this file.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="PrimaryRole" type="PrimaryRoleType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="PrimaryRoleType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>An entry exists for each Role which is in scope for a given document.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence/>
        <xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:IDREF"/>
        <xs:attribute name="displayName" use="required" type="maxStrLen100"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="CodeSystemsType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>CodeSystems defined here and referenced from subject records in the payload.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:element name="CodeSystem" type="CodeSystemType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="CodeSystemType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Each CodeSystem collection has its own section.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="concept" type="ConceptType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="maxStrLen50"/>
        <xs:attribute name="oid" use="required" type="oidStrLen50"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ConceptType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Each entry is an instance of a particular CodeSystem.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence/>
        <xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:ID"/>
        <xs:attribute name="code" use="required" type="maxStrLen12"/>
        <xs:attribute name="displayName" use="required" type="maxStrLen100"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="OrgOrganisationsType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Container for Organisation records in the payload.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Organisation" type="OrgOrganisationType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="OrgOrganisationType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>An entry for each Organisation entity in the payload.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="maxStrLen100" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Date" type="DateIVLValueType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="OrgId" type="II" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="OtherId" type="II" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
            <xs:element name="Status" type="ValMaxStrLen12" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="LastChangeDate" type="ValDateType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="GeoLoc" type="GeoLocType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Contacts" type="OrgContactsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Roles" type="OrgRolesType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Rels" type="OrgRelsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Succs" type="OrgSuccsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="AdditionalAttributes" type="OrgAdditionalAttributesType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="refOnly" use="optional" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:attribute name="orgRecordClass" use="required" type="xs:IDREF"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="OrgRelsType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>All relations for given entity are held here (optional) but if the container is present, one or more Relationship entries must be present.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Rel" type="OrgRelType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="OrgRelType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Any relationships for an entity are listed here including information about the target entity.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Date" type="DateIVLValueType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="Status" type="ValMaxStrLen12" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Target" type="TargetType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:IDREF"/>
        <xs:attribute name="uniqueRelId" use="optional" type="deciNoFrac"/>
        <xs:attribute name="derived" use="optional" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="TargetType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Contains information about the target entity for a given relationship.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="OrgId" type="II" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="PrimaryRoleId" type="TargetRoleIDType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="TargetRoleIDType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>The Primary Role of a target entity (may not conform to the list in Primary Role Scope but will comply with those listed in the OrganisationRoles CodeSystemsType).</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence/>
        <xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:IDREF"/>
        <xs:attribute name="uniqueRoleId" use="optional" type="deciNoFrac"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="OrgSuccsType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Contains any predecessor and successor organisations.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Succ" type="OrgSuccType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="OrgSuccType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Represents an individual succession for the subject record.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Date" type="DateIVLValueType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Type" type="maxStrLen12" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Type field will contain values of "Successor" or "Predecessor".</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Target" type="TargetType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="uniqueSuccId" use="required" type="deciNoFrac"/>
        <xs:attribute name="forwardSuccession" use="optional" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="OrgContactsType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>All contacts for a given entity are held here.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Contact" type="OrgContactType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="OrgContactType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>This data type supports the representation of a contact.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence/>
        <xs:attribute name="type" use="required" type="maxStrLen12"/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" use="required" type="maxStrLen255"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="OrgRolesType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>All Roles assigned to an entity are held here.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Role" type="OrgRoleType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="OrgRoleType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Role records held here and one must represent the entity Primary Role.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Date" type="DateIVLValueType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="Status" type="ValMaxStrLen12" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:IDREF"/>
        <xs:attribute name="uniqueRoleId" use="optional" type="deciNoFrac"/>
        <xs:attribute name="primaryRole" use="optional" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="OrgAdditionalAttributesType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Additional Attributes linked to a given entity (currently not in scope).</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AdditionalAttribute" type="AddAttrType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="GeoLocType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Holds Location information for each Organisation entity, which can be a LocationStringsType element or a LocationId element.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="LocationId" type="II" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Location" type="LocationStringsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="LocationStringsType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>This data type supports the representation location information in strings.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AddrLn1" type="maxStrLen75" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="AddrLn2" type="maxStrLen75" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
            <xs:element name="AddrLn3" type="maxStrLen75" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
            <xs:element name="Town" type="maxStrLen75" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
            <xs:element name="County" type="maxStrLen75" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
            <xs:element name="PostCode" type="maxStrLen15" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
            <xs:element name="Country" type="maxStrLen50" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
            <xs:element name="UPRN" type="deciNoFrac" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ANY" abstract="true">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>This data type represents an abstract type from which more specific data types are derived.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ValDateType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>This data type supports the representation of a date.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ANY">
                <xs:sequence/>
                <xs:attribute name="value" use="optional" type="xs:date"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ValTimestampType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>This data type supports the representation of a timeStamp.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ANY">
                <xs:sequence/>
                <xs:attribute name="value" use="optional" type="xs:dateTime"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="DateIVLValueType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>This is the custom date type to represent start and end dates for various components of the organisation record.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ANY">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Type" type="ValMaxStrLen12" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xs:element name="Start" type="ValDateType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xs:element name="End" type="ValDateType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="II">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>This data type supports the representation of an instance identifier.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ANY">
                <xs:sequence/>
                <xs:attribute name="root" use="required" type="oidStrLen50"/>
                <xs:attribute name="extension" use="required" type="maxStrLen12"/>
                <xs:attribute name="assigningAuthorityName" use="required" type="maxStrLen25"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="AddAttrType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Container for Additional Attribute records (currently out of scope).</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Key" type="maxStrLen50" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Value" type="maxStrLen255" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="AttributeDate" type="ValDateType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ValMaxStrLen12">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Value attribute to hold strings up to 12 characters in length.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" use="optional" type="maxStrLen12"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ValMaxStrLen15">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Value attribute to hold strings up to 15 characters in length.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" use="optional" type="maxStrLen15"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ValMaxStrLen25">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Value attribute to hold strings up to 25 characters in length.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" use="optional" type="maxStrLen25"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ValMaxStrLen50">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Value attribute to hold strings up to 50 characters in length.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" use="optional" type="maxStrLen50"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ValMaxStrLen75">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Value attribute to hold strings up to 75 characters in length.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" use="optional" type="maxStrLen75"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ValMaxStrLen100">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Value attribute to hold strings up to 100 characters in length.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" use="optional" type="maxStrLen100"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ValMaxStrLen255">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Value attribute to hold strings up to 255 characters in length.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" use="optional" type="maxStrLen255"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ValDeciNoFrac">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Value attribute to hold whole numbers up to 12 digits.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" use="required" type="deciNoFrac"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="oidStrLen50">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>This data type supports the representation of an object identifier.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="([0-9][0-9]*)(\.[0-9][0-9]*)*"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="maxStrLen12">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Defines a value as a string with a maximum length of 12.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="12"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="maxStrLen15">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Defines a value as a string with a maximum length of 15.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="15"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="maxStrLen25">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Defines a value as a string with a maximum length of 25.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="25"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="maxStrLen50">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Defines a value as a string with a maximum length of 50.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="maxStrLen75">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Defines a value as a string with a maximum length of 75.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="75"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="maxStrLen100">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Defines a value as a string with a maximum length of 100.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="maxStrLen255">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Defines a value as a string with a maximum length of 255.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="255"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="deciNoFrac">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Defines a value as a decimal, where the maximum number of digits permitted is less than or equal to 12, and limits the value to a whole number only (no decimal places).</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
            <xs:fractionDigits value="0"/>
            <xs:totalDigits value="12"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

I used the above code to create a dictionary which I converted to a dataframe using this code.
[How to create a dataframe from specific keys of a List of dictionaries in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73375139/how-to-create-a-dataframe-from-specific-keys-of-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-python)

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Not clear what the problem is. If there's already a doc to parse, how is the xsd involved in that.

Comment: If the file is too big, maybe you should try to parse it with SAX XML parser.